# Word origin / meaning of 'kernel' in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, terminology, math-history

It may be the dumbest question ever asked on math.SE, but...

---

Given a real matrix $\mathbf A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, the [column space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space) is defined as 
$$C(\mathbf A) = \{\mathbf A \mathbf x : \mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^n\} \subseteq \mathbb R^m.$$

It is sometimes called *image* or *range*.

- I'm OK with the name 'column space' because $C(\mathbf A)$ is the set of all possible [linear combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of $\mathbf A$'s column vectors.
- I'm OK with the name 'image' because if I consider $\mathbf A \mathbf x$ as a [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) then $C(\mathbf A)$ is this function's [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) (the subset of a function's [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)).
- I'm OK with the name 'range' because I can consider $C(\mathbf A)$ as a [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28mathematics%29) of a function $f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf A \mathbf x$.

Unfortunately, I'm not happy with the name [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29).
$$\ker(\mathbf A) = \{\mathbf x: \mathbf A\mathbf x = \mathbf 0\}\subseteq \mathbb R^n$$

The kernel is sometimes called *null space* and I can fairly understand where this name came from -- it's because this set contains all the elements in $\mathbb R^n$ that are mapped to zero by $\mathbf A$.

Then why is it called 'kernel'? Any historic background or colloquial meaning that I completely missed?

Comment: According to Jeff Miller's *[Earliest Known Uses of
Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html)*, the term *kernel* was first used in this meaning by Pontryagin (in translation by Lehmer) in the slightly broader context of group homomorphisms. It doesn't say why Pontryagin or Lehmer chose that particular word though.

Comment: The word "kernel" means "core" in German. Nevertheless, I think it is the nicest name of all the names you picked to exemplify about!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You mean Kern; kernel is English

Comment: @Cocopuffs Aha. ${}$

Comment: Here's my random attempt to justify the term "kernel". Say we solve $Ax = b$. First, we find a particular solution. That serves as the "shell" of the solution set. Think of it as an uninflated balloon. Members of $\ker A$ are air molecules that are injected into the balloon. The size (dimension) of $\ker A$ determines the size of the inflated balloon. As you inject $\ker A$ into the balloon (so it becomes balloon's "kernel"), it magically expands in an affine way, so the initial shell is not unique. (If no solutions exist, you don't have a balloon.)

Comment: @Tunococ, this is close to the idea of internal/external degrees of freedom (see comment under triple_sec answer).

Answer (score 33):

The word *kernel* means “seed,” “core” in nontechnical language (etymologically: it's the diminutive of *corn*). If you imagine it geometrically, the origin is the center, sort of, of a Euclidean space. It can be conceived of as the *kernel* of the space. You can rationalize the nomenclature by saying that the kernel of a matrix consists of those vectors of the domain space that are mapped into the center (*i.e.*, the origin) of the range space.

I think a somewhat analogous rationale might motivate the designation [“core”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28game_theory%29) in cooperative game theory: It denotes a particular set that is of central interest. (In this case, it denotes—loosely speaking—the set of such allocations among a given number of persons that cannot be overturned by collusion among some of them. This property lends the core a sense of stability and equilibrium, which is why it is so interesting.)

Comment: All that you write is a justification for *center* as a term, which would have occurred to the creators of the terminology if that were the idea.  I think a more likely story is the idea that the qualitative behavior of $Ax=b$ is determined by that of $Ax=0$ and the rest is an matter of whether $b$ is in a particular set or not, so in a sense accidental while the solutions for $b=0$ are more fundamental.

Comment: As I don't know who coined this term and why, yes, what I wrote is admittedly pure speculation... Your theory is also interesting, but I fail to see how it works in the case of nonsingular square matrices. In that case, the equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ _always_ has a solution, so the qualitative characterization of this equation does not depend on that of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$—all the more so because the latter has $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ as its only solution. In that case, $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is as accidental a possibility as any other!

Comment: There would be no term *kernel* if not for the nontrivial cases that it is meant to cover.  The definition then applies in the trivial cases too, but I don't see why the justification has to be equally meaningful in the cases it was not invented to describe (if all $A$ were nonsingular what would be the need for the concept?).  I find it seriously unlikely that trivial kernel was a motivating case for the concept of kernel, under any name.

Comment: I feel that we're both emphasizing different aspects of the same speculative hypothesis. But we do seem to agree in that the name “kernel” might come from the fact that the zero vector $\mathbf{0}$ has a distinguished, central role in linear algebra.

Comment: On further reflection, I think it is important to avoid the idea that the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ is more distinguished than the inhomogeneous $Ax=b$.  It is not true in geometry, and terms like *fundamental solution* illustrate that inhomogeneous solutions are sometimes viewed as more essential.  I think the precise distinction is that $b$ defines the external degrees of freedom, and the kernel the internal ("gauge") degrees of freedom of solutions of the equation.  This notion of internal/external is common, and accepting it as a metaphor, core/nucleus/kernel for internal DOF is natural.

Comment: (I will migrate my comments to the other answer, deleting the ones above, unless you would prefer to keep the conversation in place here.)

Answer (score 3):

The imagery is consistent with inhomogeneous equations $Ax = b$ where the degrees of freedom in the answer are those of $Ax = 0$ and the latter could be seen as the invariant core of the problem separate from the particularities of different $b$ (for some values there are solutions, for others there can be no solutions).

Whether this really was the historical origin I cannot say.  Of course it makes sense for group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @triple_sec it can be said that

> the kernel of a matrix consists of those vectors of the domain space
>   that are mapped into the center (i.e., the origin) of the range space.

These are those vectors that after undergoing a transformation, squished themselves into a zero vector because the determinant = 0. (That means the region squished into 0 volume); These vectors are also called free variables or non-pivot columns;

N(A) = N(RREF(A))

The kernel of a transformation is equal to the kernel of RREF of the transformation. That is the vectors that get squished in an RREF or the original matrix are going to be equal. The pivots help us define the system of equations in reduced forms. The null space helps us define the originality or loyalty of the equations/matrix transformation.

In a non-full-rank matrix-transformation say of 3D to 2D, there is a line fill of vectors that lay at the origin. [A 3D to 1D transformation](https://youtu.be/uQhTuRlWMxw?t=620) has a plane full of vectors that lay at the origin.

In `Ax = [0]` 
When **v** happens to be a 0 vector, The null space/kernel gives you all possible solutions to all the system of equations.