# Philosophical/Historical question on the word "kernel" in Algebra

Tags: math-history, philosophy

My question is little philosophical/historical, and it came to mind due to some natural curiocity.

The word kernel appears in many contexts in abstract algebra. (It also appears in other branches of Mathematics - in Fourier Analysis).

It may make one curious about its meaning in English Literature and similarity in Mathematics. In English Literature, its meaning, as per Oxford Dictionary, is  ("inner part of a nut or seed").

But, when I tried to thinks its analogy in algebra, I did not find similarity.

Can one explain who used the word "kernel" (in Algebra) first time, and whether it has analogy with the word ("kernel" in English Literature)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: See [Kernel](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/k/): "Ivar Fredholm used the French word, "noyau," in his famous paper on INTEGRAL EQUATIONS, "Sur une classe des équations fonctionnelles," Acta Math., 27, (1903), 365–390. David Hilbert put this into German as Kern in his "Grundzüge einer allgemeinen Theorie der linearen Integralgleichungen," Nachrichten von d. Königl. Ges. d. Wissensch. zu Göttingen (Math.-ph. Kl.) (1904) p. 49. The English word kernel appears in M. Bôcher's Introduction to the Study of Integral Equations (1909): "K is called the kernel of these equations.""

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I don't agree on "...belongs to History of Science and Mathematics." Its "not only about history" of the word; but its meaning analogous as in English Literature (if any). Hence, I put both (philosophical and historical) in title as well as question.

Comment: The French "noyau" means *core*; thus, the "inner part".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I searched it in books on History of Algebra - such as by van der Waerden, Kleiner etc; but found no answer to my question; then only, I put it here. (I don't get what is problem).

Comment: That about the "historical" part... IMO, there is nothing specifically "philosophical" there: often the author needs a new name and the choice can be only motivated by some analogy.

Comment: @Mauro: I agree; but the word "homomorphis" has some meaning hidden in meaning of words "homo" and "morph", from which, one can see the naming of homomorphism. But, the very close word of it - kernel - I did not find any analogy; hence put question here, as a curiosity, and due to no solution in other resources.

Comment: See this picture  https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/4-Group-Theory-4.1-Groups-Zomorodian/fefaf4467153cf32e5f9c29859f52b147a3b51d1/figure/5

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500920/word-origin-meaning-of-kernel-in-linear-algebra, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281122/why-are-these-functions-called-kernels.